# getting data from backend using axios method in react functional comonent

Tags: reactjs

i am using axios method in the functional component.. i have tried in my project...its not working properly....its showing throwing a error...like courses are not defined...please help on this question....i want get data from the back end using that i have used url...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Example =() => {
 const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
 useEffect(()=> {
    Axios.get("https://www.example.com/users/id/")
            .then(response => {
               this.setState({ courses: response.data })
                // console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
 }, [])   

 return (
            <div>
             <Col xl={12} lg={12} md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                    <div className="main-boxes">
                        <div className="index-box-head">
                            3. Courses
                                </div>
                        <div className="course-index-boxes">
                            <div className="scrolling-data">
                                <List>
                                    {courses.map((course, key) => (
                                        <ListItem className="button-class" button key={key}>
                                            <NavLink className="link-levels" exact activeClassName="activeclass" to={course.diploma_url}>
                                                {course.diploma_course}
                                            </NavLink>
                                        </ListItem>
                                    ))}

                                </List>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Col>
            </div>
         )
}
export default Example
```

Comment: So where did you define `courses`?

Comment: this.setState({ courses: response.data }).....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have `this` here it is not Class
so you should get it like this:

```
const Example =() => {
  const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=> {
    Axios.get("https://www.example.com/users/id/")
      .then(response => {
         setCourses(response.data);
         // console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }, []);
```

later:

```
{courses.map((course, index) => (                                        
  <ListItem className="button-class" button key={index}>
    <NavLink
      className="link-levels"
      exact
      activeClassName="activeclass"
      to={course.diploma_url}
    >                                                
      {course.diploma_course}
    </NavLink>
  </ListItem>
))}
```

Comment: While not a standard rule it generally is not recommended to use an array index as the key in mapped JSX. We don't know anything about the shape of each course but it is likely they do have some unique property.